# Frustrated Swift Callback

Tags: swift, asynchronous, callback

Recently I'm on a project that requires a lot of APIs Async interacting with the Server, I've tried delegating, but writing a lot of delegator is not very elegant. I've been following all the 'Swift Callback' threads on SO before, Still stucking.

```
//First try

func post(url: String, data: String, callback:(result: String) ->Void){
    callback(result: "Completed")
}

func request(url: String, data: String){
    post(url, data, { (result) in
        println(result)
    })
}

request("Hello", "World")

//prints nothing


//second try following threads

func test(txt: String, resolve: (name: String) -> Void) {
    resolve(name: "Dodo")
}
test("hello", {(name: String) in
    println(name)
})
```

What did I missed, Any help will be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. I run Xcode 7 and needed to make some modifications, but the code worked for me. If you are trying this in Playground, make sure it is actually executing. It often happens to me that I am expecting print statement to show something, but Playground is stuck and does not output anything due to an error.

Here is the code that worked for me (modified for Swift 2):

```
func post(url: String, data: String, callback:(result: String) ->Void){
    callback(result: "Completed")
}

func request(url: String, data: String){
    post(url, data: data, callback: { (result) in
        print(result)
    })
}

request("Hello", data: "World")

func test(txt: String, resolve: (name: String) -> Void) {
    resolve(name: "Dodo")
}
test("hello", resolve: {(name: String) in
    print(name)
})
```

Comment: Exactly I'm running it on Playground! So I plant it into my project and everything looks fine now. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to run your code in a playground, you need to tell Xcode to not exit (so that it can make the request in background and execute async callbacks).

Appending this to your playground should make it work:

```
import XCPlayground

XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()
```